# what is the limitation of h2 off-heap store? Where are the data stored?

Tags: h2

I am considering to take advantage of H2 Off-Heap store.  According to the doc, "Storage is pluggable. Unless pure in-memory operation is used, the default storage is to a single file."

Are the following sample code involve so-called pure in-memory operation?

```
OffHeapStore offHeap = new OffHeapStore();
MVStore s = new MVStore.Builder().
        fileStore(offHeap).open();
```

If it is, what is the limit of the off-heap memory space?

If it is not, where is the default storage file?

Answer (score 1):

`OffHeapStore` uses the **native** (**direct**) memory of Java process (not the Java **heap**), there are no files. Its maximum size depends on the amount of available memory and on JVM settings. You can set the total explicit limit for JVM with `java -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=2048M …` if default in your JVM is not suitable for you, but you also need the enough amount of free memory on your system.

`OffHeapStore` is not guaranteed to be more efficient than default in-memory storage, you have to compare them by yourself with your application.

If you don't have enough memory, you can always use persistent on-disk storage with `MVStore.Builder().fileName("…").open()`.

Comment: I see.  I used to think that the data kept in off-heap memory can be flushed to an external file.  It confused me until now.  Thanks!